# React Native toggle button and change theme simultaneously

Tags: react-native

I have issue with toggle button and changing the theme in react native. My theme context file theme-context.js

```
import React from 'react';

export const ThemeContext = React.createContext({
  theme: 'light',
  toggleTheme: () => {},
});
```

I have imported the above file and Its perfectly changing the theme. I would like to change the state of the button simultaneously. Please find the following code. How can I call the function onCheckedChange with themeContext.toggleTheme using the OnChange?

```
const ToggleTheme = () => {

const [checked, setChecked] = React.useState(false);

const themeContext = React.useContext(ThemeContext);

const onCheckedChange = (isChecked) => {
    setChecked(isChecked);
  };
      return (
      <Toggle checked={checked} onChange={themeContext.toggleTheme}>
          Change Theme
        </Toggle>
      );
    }
```

Comment: `onChange={() => themeContext.toggleTheme()}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are going to use this toggle only for toggling the theme, you can use the theme value in the context to display the toggle rather than using a local state.

```
return (
      <Toggle checked={themeContext.theme==='light'} onChange={themeContext.toggleTheme}>
          Change Theme
        </Toggle>
      );
```

If you do this once you toggle the theme it will switch value.

But if you have a requirement to call onCheckedChange, you can do this

```
 <Toggle checked={checked} onChange={()=>{
  onCheckedChange(!checked);
   themeContext.toggleTheme();
}}>
```